# How to bulk identify Google Photos media items that count towards storage quota?

Tags: google-photos

Across the years/decade as I've uploaded photos to GPhotos, some with storage offers, some without, I have photos and videos that some count towards the storage quota and most don't.

How do I find out which ones count towards my storage quota? I would like to batch download and delete them from library (I'll store them elsewhere) and recover my Google Account Storage Quota.

The Photos Web/Mobile UI has [recently begun showing if photos count towards quota](https://9to5google.com/2022/07/19/google-photos-backed-up/):

| Example of counting against quota: | Example of ***not*** counting against quota: |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Example of counting against quota] | [image: Example of counting against quota] |

Since it's being shown in the Web UI, I'm hoping there's a batch/programmatic way to identify/list/delete these media items.

Things I've looked through till now:

1. Google One Storage Management Page:
   https://one.google.com/storage/management
2. Google Drive File Quota
   management ([doesn't cover Google Photos anymore](https://blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/)):
   https://drive.google.com/drive/quota
3. Google Photos Web Quota
   management: https://photos.google.com/quotamanagement
4. Google Photos
   API documentation:
   https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview
5. (3p) GPhotos Uploader CLI (uses above API) documentation:
   https://gphotosuploader.github.io/gphotos-uploader-cli/#/configuration?id=including-and-excluding-files
6. (3p) rclone Google Photos integration:
   https://rclone.org/googlephotos/#limitations
7. Previous SE questions like: [How do I know if a video is consuming space on Google Photos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82533/how-do-i-know-if-a-video-is-consuming-space-on-google-photos) which don't focus on a batch solution and are out of date from Google's recent product developments (upto EOY 2022)
8. [Deprecated Google Picasa's Album Archive View](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/7008270?visit_id=638084710455010034-3588131865&p=aarc&rd=1): https://get.google.com/albumarchive/ ([deprecated as of July 19, 2023](https://9to5google.com/2023/06/16/google-album-archive-photos-delete/))

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Here is another similar question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/163420/how-can-i-tell-how-much-space-is-taken-up-by-photos-vs-videos-on-google-photos

Comment: @daniel I have not found an answer yet. This might require Python+Selenium hacking to automate it though going over 400k+ media items from my Library seems like it'll trigger all sorts of throttling behavior from Google.

Comment: Build your own throttling into your script so you don't trigger google's throttling?  I mean, if it is happening online, in the cloud, is there really a rush to get it done *tomorrow*, especially when we have already gone this long waiting for a solution?  I personally don't mind if it takes one month, or even two or three months, to slowly crawl all my media - as long as it gets done in the end.